# No CAPTCHA when registering new Stack Exchange OpenID account

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, stack-exchange-openid

When [registering new Stack Exchange OpenID account](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register), it says:

> Enter a valid email **and solve the CAPTCHA**, and we'll send you a link to create an account

Emphasis mine. Only problem is... there is no Captcha in the form:

> [image]

Either the text should be changed (e.g. "Enter a valid email and password...") or CAPTCHA should be added to help fight spam bots.

Note that in the past, it used to show the CAPTCHA as extra step or after filling the rest of the fields, but not anymore as [proved by other user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222615/no-captcha-when-registering-new-stack-exchange-openid-account?noredirect=1#comment724223_222615) who successfully submitted the form without ever proving he's actually a human being and not a bot.

Comment: Did you fill out the form?  The CAPTCHA appears after filling everything in (at least it did for me)

Comment: @psubsee2003 nope, didn't want to create new account for nothing... but still, in my opinion the CAPTCHA should appear in the same form, not as extra step.

Comment: @psubsee2003, do you mean after pressing that button? Or just when filling in the details. (Either way, I agree with Shadow Wizard: confusing.)

Comment: @Arjan I don't remember which actually now.  But I remember it appeared when I was trying to sign up for an SE login.

Comment: Ok, I just bit the bullet and created a new SE login for my low rep test account.... no CAPTCHA.  Bug, bug bug

Comment: @psubsee2003 lol, thanks for saving me from adding yet another useless account! Will update the post to make it clear.

Comment: `if (user == 'Shadow Wizard') ShowCaptcha();`

Comment: @Oded good enough for me! ;)

Comment: The Captcha will show up under certain circumstances, guess the wording is there to account for when it _is_ there (it was probably always showing at a certain point in time but the wording never changed). Something for Monday morning ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "and solve the CAPTCHA" text will only appear when...

... there is a CAPTCHA on the page.

Comment: Awesome! Simply simple. :D

Comment: Oh, and of course, if it is you, double the captcha ;)